# Strange behavior with Silverlight 5 when downloading file in browser.

Tags: c#, silverlight, internet-explorer

I am working on `Silverlight 5` application,where the client requirement is to `download the file`.

The download is working fine in our organization,but the problem is with the client,they are able to download the file in `browsers(Chrome and Firefox)`,they can't with `Internet Explorer`,Why..?

We checked the `IE settings` and `Silverlight plugin permissions` in client browser,everything is correct. What is the issue.?

We checked in the `IE version 10 and 11` in our organization it's just working fine and we installed the same version in client,but it's not working.

Comment: Check if the problem is only for that particular system or all the client system.

Comment: It's with all client system.